# Netbeans: Loading an existing cloned GIT repo

Tags: git, ubuntu, netbeans

I have a large local GIT repository which I am already working on.
This repository contains several other netbeans projects in it.
I cannot restructure this GIT repo to contain single projects, as it does not belong to me.

I would like to use the graphical Netbeans GIT client on this entire repository

However, I do not want to reclone this repository, or move it to a different path. Can I somehow load this allready cloned repository into the netbeans IDE?

For now, I hacked it by defining a fake PHP project in the repository's root directory. This project contains no php (it's a bunch of small c++ projects), but I wanted a root project that won't try to build anything.

As I've found myself in this situation many times (start using netbeans after I've cloned and compiled) , I am looking for a less "hacky" way to do this.

PS: Please don't start an offtopic discussion on the merits of using GIT from command line. I prefer UI for GIT over command line. Netbeans is my choice of git GUI for Ubuntu, as other **free** GUI clients have incomplete functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Favorites to "open" any directory in NetBeans:

- open Favorites by Window -> Favorites
- right click in the Favorites window and select `Add to Favorites`
- select the directory (the repository)
- it is now added among Favorites, right click on it

=> there are multiple actions, including e.g. Git which works the same way as if invoked on project